# Spring Data Neo4j - Optimistic Locking

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

1. Is there a Google group for SDN or is StackOverflow the only place to ask questions about SDN?
2. I found this issue on Spring JIRA about [Optimistic Locking](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-551) using @Version attributes.

Until this one is implemented, **how can I handle this using the typical Repository pattern?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the @Version attribute is not yet supported by SDN, it ist planned though to add support for optimistic concurrency/locking for SDN 4

Comment: Thanks Michael, but the comment on the issue states "On hold till MVCC". So is MVCC support going to appear in SDN 4? Also do you have a timeline in mind, as to when SDN 4 is going to be released?

Answer (score 5):

I can answer to your first question :

There is a [Neo4j google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/neo4j) where you can ask general questions on concepts and data modelization in Neo4j (SDN too)

There is also a Slack group which you can join by going [here](http://neo4j-users-slack-invite.herokuapp.com/). You will find many channels where you can chat directly with the community and Neo4j developpers (including SDN developpers). I particulary like Slack for straight foreward questions and dialogs. There are channels about almost every Neo4j topic, SDN, and language specific integrations.

However StackOverflow is the main place to post code samples and related questions.

Hope you can find what you are looking for in one of these communication tools ;)